# Do modern c++ compilers autovectorize code for 24bit image processing?

Tags: c++, image-processing, compiler-optimization, vectorization, 24-bit

Do compilers like gcc, visual studio c++, the intel c++ compiler, clang, etc. vectorize code like the following?

```
std::vector<unsigned char> img( height * width * 3 );
unsigned char channelMultiplier[3];

// ... initialize img and channelMultiplier ...

for ( int y = 0; y < height; ++y )
    for ( int x = 0; x < width; ++x )
        for ( b = 0; b < 3; ++b )
            img[ b+3*(x+width*y) ] = img[ b+3*(x+width*y) ] * 
                                     channelMultiplier[b] / 0x100;
```

How about the same for 32 bit image processing?

Comment: This depends totally on which compiler you're using and which optimisation options you have chosen. Furthermore, you can ask your compiler to produce an assembly listing and inspect it yourself.

Comment: Say you choose the strongest optimization options available.

Comment: It is unlikely that you have a decently optimized code produced by compiler without any hints from your side. This is the reason packages like Intel Performance Primitives exist in first place: they offer performance fine tuning the compilers cannot reach through optimization. However, as Greg said above, with you particular code it is up to you to look at the assmebly and check what optimizations are effectively there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not think your tripple loop will auto-vectorize. IMO the problems are:

- Memory is accessed through an object type std::vector. AFAIK I don't think any compiler will auto-vectorize std::vector code unless the access operators [] or () are inlined but still, it is not clear to me that it will be auto-vectorized.
- Your code suffers from memory aliasing, i.e. the compiler doesn't know if the memory you refer to `img` is accessed from another memory pointer and this will most likely block the vectorization. Basically you need to define a plain double array and hint the compiler that no other pointer is referring to that same location. I think you can do that using `__restrict`.  `__restrict` tells the compiler that this pointer is the only pointer pointing to that memory location and that there are no other pointers, and thus there is no risk of side effects.
- The memory is not aligned by default and even if the compiler manages to auto-vectorize, the vectorization of unaligned memory is a lot slower than that of aligned memory. You need to ensure your memory is 32 memory bit address aligned to exploit auto-vectorization and AVX to the maximum and 16 bit address aligned to exploit SSE to the maximum i.e. always align to 32 memory bit address. This you can do dynamically via:

  ```
  double* buffer = NULL;
  posix_memalign((void**) &buffer, 32, size*sizeof(double));
  ...
  free(buffer);
  ```

in MSVC you can do this with `__declspec(align(32)) double array[size]` but you have to check with the specific compiler you are using to make sure you are using the correct alignment directives.

Another important thing, if you use GNU compiler use the flag `-ftree-vectorizer-verbose=6` to check whether your loop is being auto-vectorized. If you use the Intel compiler then use `-vec-report5`. Note that there are several levels of verbosity and information output i.e. the 6 and 5 numbers so checkout the compiler documentation. The higher the verbosity level the more vectorization information you will get for every loop in your code but the slower the compiler will compile in Release mode.

In general, I have been always surprised how NOT easy is to get the compiler to auto-vectorize, it is a common mistake to assume that because a loop looks canonical then the compiler will auto-vectorize it auto-magically.

UPDATE: and one more thing, make sure your `img` is actually page-aligned `posix_memalign((void**) &buffer, sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE), size*sizeof(double));` (which implies AVX and SSE aligned). The problem is that if you have a big image, this loop will most likely end-up page-switching during execution and that's also very expensive. I think this is what is so-called [TLB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer) misses.